# Repeat data verification on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I have an issue which is bothering me for quite some time. Namely, I am developing a web site for a certain organization and there is going to be a lot of data entry by the citizens and other legal entities. For that matter I want to secure an application as much as I can both from user entries and some sort of malfunction or malicious use.

The idea is following. I have an entity, lets call it EntityA, which is parrent of EntityB. Both entities take uniqueidentifier (GUID) as their data type in the database (primary keys). EntityB has a foreign key to EntityA. When an HTTP GET version of Create action is executed the following rules are checked and all three **must** satisified:

1. ID passed to action must not equal to Guid.Empty (This ID is a value in EntityA.Id)
2. EntityA must exist (EntityA.Id == ID)
3. EntityB must not exist (EntityA and EntityB can only have one-to-one relationship).

This is all fine when presenting a data entry screen to a user. My question is, should I perform the checks again on POST? If I have a malicious user, he/she can use let's say Fiddler as a proxy and change the data prior to letting it go through to the application. Therefore, the above rules could be circumvented on POST. Does anyone have a good strategy for the above scenario? Should I recheck the values again (going back to the database once more to perform the same check) or should I try to store, for example ID in TempData and access it again on POST to compare that ID against the one either passed to action or added to EntityB model? Is there a better way to do this?

Therefore, the goals are to avoid the code being repeated and to create a secure code.

EDIT: It would be good to avoid visiting database again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check the existence of `EntityA` again (and as I understand it, the nonexistence of an `EntityB`).

**As for code duplication:** The check can be easily refactored to a unified method.

**As for performance:** First of all, you must realize that security is on highest priority and if it involves extra hit to the database - so be it. *Having said that,* there are definitely some good solutions to avoid that hit. For example, saving IDs (that you found legit in the first stage) in a `Cache` object.

*Note:* From your question, I figure that your GUIDs are "secret". i.e. other users don't see them. If this is not the case, I believe that you should add an extra check that validates that an ID passed indeed "belongs" to the authenticated user.

Comment: Ofer, thanks for your response. Last night I figured out that because there is a relationship established on a database level, it will not be necessary to check whether EntityA exists because EntityB will not be added successfully. However, there is no other way but to repeat the check in POST.